# How to migrate /var back into the main partition

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition

I have two harddisks, mounted on / and /var

I need to migrate the /var partition back into the / partition.

What are the steps required to do this?

Comment: [Search is your friend](http://serverfault.com/search?q=move+%2Fvar)

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything preventing you from changing where your secondary disk mounts? I would unmount it, then mount it at a new point such as /newpointpoint then make sure /var still exists on your disk mounted at /. At that point you can just move everything from /newmountpoint/ to /var/.